# UrlHelper.Action throws exception when controller is being routed to through a custom IRouter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am in the process of porting a medium-sized legacy ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core .Net 7.0.

This system have among other things a couple of custom routers to resolve controller and action based on the incoming requests. The Razor views in the system relies heavily on `Url.Action` calls to produce links between the actions. (The included repro uses `Controller.Url.Action` instead to make it more brief.)

As long as I reach the controller directly through "normal" routing `Url.Action` works, but when the same controller and action are being invoked from my custom `IRouter` implementation `Url.Action` call throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Could not find an IRouter associated with the ActionContext. If your application is 
using endpoint routing then you can get a IUrlHelperFactory with dependency injection 
and use it to create a UrlHelper, or use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator.
```

I have tried to resolve a custom IUrlHelperFactory and also LinkGenerator to work around these issues, but so far I have not succeeded.

Is there anything wrong in my setup and/or router, or is this an unsupported scenario?

Repro:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; });
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(null, "home/index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    routes.Routes.Add(new CustomRouter(routes.DefaultHandler));                         
});

app.Run();

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Index() => Url.Action("Index", "Home");
}

public class CustomRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter defaultHandler;

    public CustomRouter(IRouter defaultHandler)
    {
        this.defaultHandler = defaultHandler;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path != "/test")
        {
            return;
        }

        var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
             { "controller", "Home" }, 
             { "action", "Index" }
        };

        context.RouteData = new RouteData(dictionary);
        await defaultHandler.RouteAsync(context);
    }

    public VirtualPathData? GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context) => null;
}
```

| Url | Expected output | Actual output | Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /home/index | /home/index | /home/index | X |
| /test | /home/index | System.InvalidOperationException |  |

Comment: Have you looked at the source to see how it's trying to get the `IRouter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my attempt to set the route data values, I "overwrote" the `context.RouteData.Routes` list by accident.

This in turn causes the `Url.Action` call to throw an exception as it requires at least one item in the `context.RouteData.Routes` to be able to resolve the path.

My solution was to replace:

```csharp
    context.RouteData = new RouteData(dictionary);
```

with:

```csharp
    foreach (var pair in dictionary)
    {
        context.RouteData.Values[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

```
public class CustomRouter : IRouter
{
    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path != "/test")
        {
            return;
        }
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(context.HttpContext, context.RouteData, new ControllerActionDescriptor
        {
            ControllerName = "Home",
            ActionName = "Index"
        });

        // Create UrlHelper using the ActionContext
        var urlHelperFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
        var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);

        // Redirect to the "/home/index" action
        context.Handler = async ctx =>
        {
            var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
            ctx.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public VirtualPathData? GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context) => null;
}
```

Program.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(null, "home/index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    routes.Routes.Add(new CustomRouter());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately in my scenario - redirecting the user is not a viable option.